# C/C++ Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Tags: c++, c

Выбивает ошибку: Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением
в `buffer_table.company = table[i].company;` Вот весь код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <Windows.h>

struct OfficePackagesTable
{
char name[11], company[11];
int quality, score;
};

int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

short min; // Индекс минимального элемента
const short rows = 4;
OfficePackagesTable table[rows]; // Создаём объект на основе структуры OfficePackagesTable, даём ему название 
OfficePackagesTable buffer_table; // Буферный объект для дальнейшей сортировки

// Ввод данных
for (int i = 0; i < rows-1; i++)
{
    printf("%d. Введите -> Название | Компания | Количество | Цена \n", i + 1);
    scanf("%s", table[i].name);
    if (!strcmp(table[i].name, "***")) break;
    scanf("%s", table[i].company);
    scanf("%d", &table[i].quality);
    scanf("%d", &table[i].score);
}

printf("|-----------------------------------------------------------------| \n");
printf("|                          Офисные пакеты                         | \n");
printf("|-----------------------------------------------------------------| \n");
printf("|    Название    |    Компания    |    Количество    |    Цена    | \n");
printf("|----------------|----------------|------------------|------------| \n");
// Выводим фактические данные
for (int i = 0; i < rows-1; i++) {
    printf("|   %10s   |   %10s   |  %10d      |%10d  | \n", table[i].name, table[i].company, table[i].quality, table[i].score);
}
printf("|-----------------------------------------------------------------| \n");

// Сортировка массива
for (int i = 0; i < rows - 2; i++) {
    // Указываем, минимальный элемент является первым
    min = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < rows - 1; j++) {
        // Если текущий элемент меньше минимального, он становится минимальным
        if (strcmp(table[min].name, table[j].name) > 0) min = j; // strcmp сравнивает строки
        // Перестановка первого и минимального элемента
        if (min > i)
        {
            strcpy(buffer_table.name, table[i].name);
            buffer_table.company = table[i].company;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Попробовал различные варианты, предлагаемые в интернете - никак не идёт.

Comment: buffer_table.company это константный указатель и изменять ты его не можешь. И вообще это не C++ а C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*buffer_table.company* опеределено как *char company[11];*. Т.е. это указатель на область памяти из 11 байт. Эта область памяти выделена компилятором во время компиляции. Соответственно, указатель на неё - это **константа** которая не может изменяться во время выполнения программы. Соответственно, у Вас выдаётся ошибка присвоения константе:

> Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Если Вы хотите работать с **разными** строками, то есть два варианта:

1. Оставить опеределение структуры *OfficePackagesTable* как есть, но присваивание значения выполнять копированием строки: *strncpy(buffer_table.company, table[i].company, 10);*
2. Заменить статический массив символов на указатель и менять значение указателя:

   struct OfficePackagesTable
   {
   char *name, *company;
   int quality, score;
   };

   . . .

   buffer_table.company = strndup(table[i].company, 11);

Обратите внимание значение параметра *n* в функциях *strncpy* и *strndup* - там тонкости с 0-символом.

Comment: Все-таки `company` это массив, а не указатель.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat *company[11]* - это **массив**. А *company* - это **указатель** на первый элемент массива.

Comment: `company[11]` - это несуществующий 11-ый элемент массива. :Р `company` во многих случаях *неявно преобразуется* в указатель на свой первый элемент, но не всегда.